# Provide a Redux store to utility methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a JS design question about how to provide a redux store to files that aren't react components. I have a typical react-redux application. Instead of calling fetch directly from my react components, I currently make all of my service calls in a centralized simple functional utility method file called fetches.js.

```
const mainFetch(uri, onSuccess, options) {
    fetch(uri, options).then(response => {
        onSuccess(response);
    });
}

const export fetchDogs = (onSuccess) => {
    mainFetch('/dogs', onSuccess, { method: 'GET' });
}

const export fetchCats = (onSuccess) => {
    mainFetch('/cats', onSuccess, { method: 'GET' });
}
```

I realized that it'd be useful for my application to know exactly which of these requests we're currently waiting for. So I was thinking of adding this information to my redux state so that I could update mainFetch to look something like:

```
const mainFetch(uri, onSuccess, options, requestId) {
    store.dispatch({type: 'STARTED_REQUEST', request: requestId);

    fetch(uri, options).then(response => {
        store.dispatch({type: 'FINISHED_REQUEST', request: requestId);
        onSuccess(response);
    });
}
```

But there's one problem, fetches.js has no access to the redux store. I could add a 'store' param to all of the methods in fetches.js, however I was thinking there'd be a better JS design pattern. Maybe initializing a class in App.js or something, similarly to how react-redux uses the Provider and 'connect' to provide the store to all child components. I'm new to JS so I was wondering how an experienced JS developer would solve this problem.

Comment: Why access `store.dispatch` directly? A better design is to stick to `react-redux` You could start with redux-thunk for promises, I guess. You can extract functionality to helper functions but they should be unaware of a store. Thunks should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is lacking a middleware to handle the promises.

The basic idea is when you dispatch a Promise, from the code where you are 'calling' these 'fetch' functions, there would be a middle ware which would take the action dispatched and dispatch other actions such as 'Started fetching' and 'fetching ended' to mark the asynchronous flow.

A good start would be this link on the official site of redux - https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncflow

A middleware - https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware